# Could the Species 8472 'Imposters' reproduce?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, races

In the Star Trek: Voyager episode "In the Flesh", Species 8472 built a training facility with a simulation of Starfleet Command & parts of San francisco. There they genetically modified themselves to appear as members several Starfleet species. 
My question is, if there genetic aterations were as extremely sophisticated as the Doctor claimed than could they reproduce & have babies, either amongst themselve or with members of the species they are imitating. Also, if they could would that child be Species 8472, some kind of hybrid (maybe like Spock or B'Elanna) or, for example, would the child be a "full blooded member" of the species that was being imitated ?

Comment: There is, unfortunately, nowhere near-enough information to give even an approximate answer to this. One would assume that, yes, if the genetic alterations were complete enough then reproduction would be possible, but there is no way to tell how complete said alterations were based on the episode in question.

Comment: In the most optimistic scenario, they'd be anatomically identical to humans. Then the question would be, if the agent they use to stay altered passes the placental barrier. And if it does it cannot be said what it does with the foetus - if anything at all. Since we dont know, what the serum does, there is really no telling what would happen.

Comment: Except it is explicitly stated that they are not anatomically similar to humans. They have a biogenic field that can mask their life signs or masquerade as humans, but a simple blood test or micro cellular scan reveals their true nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of the Species 8472 imposters as seen in Voyager were not true changes to humanoid form.  They were reshaping themselves structurally to emulate humans and fool casual bio scans.  Unless they have some way of disabling their immune system @Hiram is correct, it is quite active in attacking organisms outside the body.

In "Scorpion 1" Voy s3x26 we see that not only is the biology of Species 8372 able to defend against borg nanites it also will attack other species as seen with the dead borg and the infection after Harry comes in contact on the disabled cube.  Also, their biogenic field makes them nearly invisible to sensors and can prevent transporter lock.  It is very possible that it can be repurposed to return face biosigns to sensors.

In "In the Flesh" Voy s5x04, we see that their transformation is not externally applied, but an internal process of restructuring their biology and their biogenic field to look and scan as and Federation race.  As individuals lose control of themselves they revert back to their true forms.  Also, the changes were not to DNA as a simple dna test, not a scan, was able to reveal the imposters.

During "Someone to Watch Over Me" Voy s5x22 the Doctor remarks "Species 8472 appears to have as many as five sexes."  This would indicate that the cultural exchange at the end of "In the Flesh" included their mating process.  It also shows that they require five different gametes to produce offspring.

Between the lack of necessary gametes, the species's incredibly proactive immune response, and that their alterations are literally only skin deep it is unlikely that a crossbreeding would succeed without major intervention.  As well as their view of our galaxy as a "threat to their genetic integrity" it is unlikely a crossbreeding would be attempted willingly by them.

Comment: It's Species 8[47](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/47)2  ;)

Comment: Whoops, that is what I get for copypasta from the question.

Comment: Weeell, in the question no longer (I hadn't noticed it there for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Species 8472 would not be able to produce in human form, as they mentioned in another episode 8472 has 5 genders, and when they take human form, they only have 2.

Comment: If the change was complete enough, they would produce human offspring by using the two human sexes.  This doesn't really answer anything, unless you have a reference that says they do not

Answer (score -3):

No they would not be able to produce a hybrid. If they had intercourse with a women the women would become infected by their cells. If they had intercourse with a male, their body would kill off all of the seaman . There immune systems are completely resistant to outside forces which is why the borg cant assimilate them.The borg talk about not being able to assimilate them in s04e01 Scorpian part 2. If there genetic material enters a foreign host it proceeds to start to kill the host off. This is from the startrek wiki [startrek wiki](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_8472), and wikipedia. This is both in reference to voyager as well as STO. They also have 5 sexes, as well as not being genetically altered from the outside they are able to do all genetic alterations on command internally.  We see them attack in voyager with their claws as well leaving infection behind in the victim which is further proof that their genetic material is Poisonous and attempts to kill anyone infected. (hence why having sex with one to produce a hybrid is a bad idea. )

Comment: This is a very poor answer, with absolutely no sourcing, not to mention the punctuation. I almost feel like I should delete it because it almost seems like it's unnecessarily sexual, but given the subject matter it's hard to ping it for that. Needless to say, this needs work to be an acceptable answer. It also has the serious issue of being incorrect, at least if I'm remember my *Voyager* correctly. Downvote from me.

Comment: Would the aggressive immune response still be present when they are imitating another species ?

Comment: @Himarm: So I shouldn't downvote you because you edited your answer, to add more information, none of it relevant, and a single link, to a website of little repute?

Comment: @JamesSheridan Memory Alpha is of _very high_ reputability (and it gets sourced in tons of answers on this site because of that)

Comment: @Izkata: I should have clarified that it was that particular **page** on *Memory Alpha* I had a problem with, not the site itself. There are at least four warnings of "This information may not be accurate" on the page Himarm linked.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Ah, alright then.  But the infectious part [does have onscreen evidence](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YZJHuOHka8c/UrhrMiVm19I/AAAAAAAAS9M/qSJB90y03KE/s1600/scorpion1174.jpg)

Comment: @Izkata: That has little, if any, bearing on the actual question though.

Comment: @JamesSheridan It answers the other half of the question, the part on hybrids

Comment: @Izkata: I guess you're right there. Doesn't really make sense if we follow the theory of the genetic alterations though.

Comment: Seaman? Really?